# Find my lines in repository by specific pattern

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have git repository. I want to find specific lines, that I was write.

For example, I want to see all my lines with text: TODO, todo, FIXME, fixme.

I know about git grep, but it show lines of all authors. But I want to see only my TODO.

I'm use IDEA, but it do not have filter in TODO by author.

I'm confused. Can someone help me?

**UPD** IDEA: VCS integration for TODO is not possible right now

Comment: [Answered in the forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000123330-Can-I-filter-TODO-FIXME-list-to-show-only-my-tasks-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this simple command, use `git grep` to get result, then use `awk` to split the result, inside `awk`, use `grep blame` to get more information, finally use `grep` to filter the output.

```
$ git grep -n "TODO" | awk -F: '{system("git blame -f -L "$2","$2" "$1)}' |grep "The Author Name"
```

Comment: bash 4.3.46
$: command not found
What's package I should install simh or systemd? Or anything else?

Comment: @YShinkarev `git`, `awk`/`gawk`, and `grep`

Comment: Oh, understand, I get error, because "grep" and "|" has no space.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer :

you can look at the commit you created (where you were the author), and where the diff introduced a new "TODO" :

```
git log --author="My Name" -S TODO -p
```

---

A second way could be :

- find files with a `TODO` tag
- run `git blame` on each of these files
- and keep lines, with a `TODO` flag, and where you are mentionned as the author

Something like :

```
# get file list :
grep -r . -i -E "(TODO|FIXME)" -l   > list.txt
# check each file :
cat list.txt | while read file; do
    git blame $file | grep "My Name" | grep -i -E (TODO|FIXME)
done
```

Note that if someone else edited the line (for example : reindented the line), `git blame` will mention this other person's name as the author.
And conversely : if you modified such a line, your name will be displayed in `git blame`'s output.

---

If the author's name is not specified in the `TODO` line, you have to cross the file content along with the history of the file in git - in order to be able to match this line's author. The IDE would have to do the same kind of work.

The thing is, it is hard (if not impossible) to do this in an exact manner : it is common to have commits who are rewritten in git's history (rebase, squash, ...), and although git tries to preserve the author of a commit when it makes sense, sometimes the "original" author of a commit can be lost.

Comment: Hm, seems `git log --author="My Name" -S TODO -p` return me all my lines